# Ternary operator showing checked exception with imageProvider

Tags: android, flutter, dart

No exception is shown when I use the same type of imageProvider but it's showing an exception when use a ternary operator.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGfSY.png]

```
CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundImage: imageFile != null
                      ? FileImage(File(imageFile!.path))
                      : AssetImage("assets/images/camera.png")),
            ),
```

Comment: Please do not add screenshots of code without also supplying the code in text form.  Additionally its better to include the image embedded in the question as opposed to a link.

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to use it properly...next time sure i will care about it

Comment: Two are different return type that's why show error. This is not actually problem of ternary operator.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this:

```
  imageFile != null ?
 CircleAvatar(
  backgroundImage:  FileImage(File(imageFile!.path))) :  
 CircleAvatar(
    backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/camera.png")),
```